# ! LaTeX Error: File 'figures/UILogoLG3L' not found

Tags: pdftex, external-files

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/

I downloaded the cover letter.tex, and I'm trying to 'typeset' it. So I press the green play button in TeXworks, and that's what I get.

> ! LaTeX Error: File `figures/UILogoLG3L' not found.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.14 }
>        %
>   ?

Comment: Do you have a file `UILogoLG3L` (with some graphic extension such as `.png`, `.jpg` or `.pdf`) in the subdirectory `figures` to begin with?

Comment: I have uiuc_logo.eps That's what the author has on his website.

Comment: Well, you should call *that* file.

Comment: As it's not of much value for the public, it's just a file name issue, I'll close this question as too localized. If there's any reason to let it open, edit it or comment and let us know. It can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

That error means that it's trying to use an image file that doesn't exist.  If you download the logo from the webpage (at http://www.matthewjmiller.net/files/cover_letters/uiuc_logo.eps), create a `figures` subdirectory, place the logo in that `figures` subdirectory (under the directory that contains your `.tex` file), and rename the logo file to `UILogoLG3L.eps`, you should be able to compile the document successfully.

Comment: It worked, it doesn't take .eps for some reason, so what I did was convert the eps into a jpg, and stick it into a folder named 'figures'. the figures folder is where the .tex file is. But now I have another problem, it's saying: Couldn't find `bchr.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font bchr7t.
======================================================================

! Font OT1/bch/m/n/10=bchr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.44 \begin{document}
                     
?

Comment: I think you have to use LaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to work with EPS files. You could convert from EPS to PDF so that it works with pdfLaTeX. The EPS → PDF conversion will preserve the file format better as it's a scalable (vector) format.  As for the missing font, that is Bitstream Charter and is provided by the [`charter`](http://ctan.org/pkg/charter) package. It should be supplied by MikTeX, though it may not be automatically installed.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have to download the logo image, then create a folder "figures" and put the logo image in the folder

Comment: I downloaded the logo image, but it is uiuc_logo.eps . But if I rename it, where do I have to put it?