# Can't Remove Date from newlfm

Tags: newlfm

The date in the picture below is still appearing. If I remove the `\begin{newlfm}` and `\end{newlfm}` lines, it removes the date. But I also need to have things in my `newlfm` like the body of my cover letter. I need to remove that date, I can set my own date without it automating itself.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,sigleft]{newlfm}
 \usepackage{charter}

 \widowpenalty=1000
 \clubpenalty=1000

 \newsavebox{\Luiuc}
 \sbox{\Luiuc}{%
     \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%



     }%
 }%

 \begin{document}
 \begin{newlfm}

 Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of

 \end{newlfm}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Are you guys giving up hope on me? Or the problem. Please don't give up hope on me, I'm trying really hard!

Comment: @piratepartypumpkin I am few months old newbie like you trying to help you, Be patient and calm, you will succeed. My knowledge is also very limited. Meanwhile looking into http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm

Comment: Maybe I have to edit something in the newlfm.cls or whatever it is. I can't even find that file.

Comment: @piratepartypumpkin can you join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Comment: @texenthusiast Sorry, I meant more the fact that I repeatedly edited/tried to edit the question while piratepartypumpkin kept changing things (images, code). Also, I was coming from the other question from the same OP which was a bit confusing... I wanted to explain [how to ask a good question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), but it seemed so difficult and I had work. I couldn't help with the specific problem anyway, so I thought I would just let others take charge.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove the date, set it to nothing/empty using `\dateset{}` or to something specific, like `\dateset{12 December 2013}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can state the global option `dateno` at the beginning:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,sigleft,dateno]{newlfm}
```